# Java object to json, how to serialize reference by path

Tags: java, json, serialization, xpath, jackson

I have a graph style Java object, actually it is an [Abstract syntax tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree), but with some reference links so the structure is a graph.

```
class Root {
    //A list of variable definition
    List<Variable> variables;
}

class Variable {
    String name;
    //the expression to define this variable
    Expression exp;
}

class Expression {
    //...some other nodes to make up this expression
}

//...Many node classes

//one of the nodes making up Expression
class SomeNodeInExpression {
    //refer to another variable which is inside the same root
    Variable referring; 
}
```

**Update** References are inside the same root, so there is no requirement to refer to another document

Now the requirement is to serialize a Root object to JSON.

By default of many JSON libraries, a variable will be serialized every time a reference comes. I do not want it because it causes the JSON unnecessarily large.
Jackson has settings that it can serialize `Variable referring` as a reference by id of the target object, but this has two problems in my requirement:

1. If the reference comes earlier than the definition, reference will be serialized as full node data, while definition is just an ID. This is not what I want.
2. I prefer more useful representation on the referring property, than just an node ID. -- That is a path from the Root, something like XPath or JSONPath.

So I'm trying to customize JacksonSerializer on the type `SomeNodeInExpression` and getting the following:

```
class SomeNodeInExpressionSerializer extends JsonSerializer<SomeNodeInExpression> {
    Root root;
    @Override
    public void serialize(SomeNodeInExpression value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jgen.writeStringField("referingPath", createReferingPath(root, value));
    }

    private String createReferingPath(Root root, SomeNodeInExpression value){
        //Don't know what to do now
    }
}
```

Then I researched on some Java XPath-like libraries, e.x. [JXPath](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/), [Java JsonPath](http://code.google.com/p/json-path/) and found both of them only support "get object from path", but no "get path from two objects" (at least I did not find).

So at last, my question is:

1. Can I do "get path from two objects" by using some library, Or I must implement it by own using a lot of reflection code?
2. Is there any existing easy solution just for the title of this question?

Comment: If you use Jackson which you seem to do given the tags, you can use `@JsonBackReference` to avoid "serial serialization"

Comment: @fge Thanks for comment. It seems `@JsonBackReference` is for solving two-way linkage, but here we do not have such problem

Comment: Sorry then, I misread, I thought this was your problem :/

Comment: Uhm, re-reading... Maybe JSON Reference?

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is not a proper answer since I don't fully understand your question; however, "know" that you have two addressing mechanisms in JSON:

- [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901);
- [JSON Reference](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03) (which uses JSON Pointer for fragments).

Since your references look to be only local to your document (but again I may be misled, I don't fully understand your problem) then you can make do with a custom property which value is a string, representing a JSON Pointer:

```
{ "ptr": "/path/from/root" }
```

Otherwise, if you have to reference other documents, you have to have a URI to that document and use JSON Reference, like so:

```
{ "$ref": "uri://to/other.json#/path/into/that/other.json" }
```

HOWEVER: the draft mentions that if you use a JSON Reference, other object members SHALL be ignored; so this may not be what you want either...

Just my .02 bitcoins.

Note that I have a JSON Pointer implementation if you are interested.

Comment: Sorry for my poor explanation that confuses you. I want the JSON pointer, exactly. I don't need to reference other documents. The method `createReferingPath` is trying to create such `"/path/from/root"`. The purpose is that JS client could get the target node by the root node and a reference path easily. I think the syntax of the path should be something common(XPath, JsonPath) that Java and JS could both read/write with some library.